# what is the xcode code for current image center?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

when you wish to know the text of a label you use labelName.text what is the equivalent for image.center?

Answer (score 2):

image.center is exactly what you use.

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(image.center));
NSLog(@"%f",image.center.x);
NSLog(@"%f",image.center.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

well..it seems there is no property for it...weird ( or i don't know about it..lol)

do something like :

```
CGPoint imageCenter=CGPointMake(image.size.width/2,image.size.height/2);
```